# Is it possible to use django's custom template tags to insert code in other blocks in the template?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-custom-tags

I'm writing a custom template tag that wraps an HTML element with some code to make it editable. This is backed up by some CSS, and JS that takes care of sending the data to the server to save it.

This component requires the inclusion of

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../myscript.js"></script>
```

at the bottom of the page and

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../mystyle.css">
```

at the top.

I already have two "js" and "css" template blocks in the page template.

**My question - is there a way for for the custom template tag to include these scripts once in the relevant page blocks, if my tag is present?**

IE I put in:

```
    { % mytag %} <div>editable element</div> { % endmytag %}
```

and the "js" and "css" template blocks gets populated with the relevant script\link tags?

(I don't want to preinclude those in every page, as only some of my pages will use this tag)

Answer (score 1):

You might try using [Django-Sekizai](https://github.com/ojii/django-sekizai) from within the template your custom tag renders to add CSS and JS files to another block, which is what Sekizai is designed to do. I use it extensively with Django-CMS based projects, but I haven't tried your use case.