# Django asset manager for Views or template tags?

Tags: django

I come to Django having used the Yii2 PHP framework. One of the good features about that is it allows you to create asset files for CSS and JS which are then loaded into the base layout file at runtime. This allows you to keep the base template clean of CSS and JS markup within the head and at the bottom of the HTML document. The CSS and JS files you specify in the asset file are automatically placed in the correct position in the document and you can also specify dependencies if needed.

At the moment, with Django I am having to edit the base.html file manually which is not ideal.

I know you can use the Media class for forms, and in admin.py, which does a similar job. However, what I would like to do is to something like this (for example) in inclusion template tags or in a class based view perhaps.

Is this possible?

Many thanks!

UPDATE

Here is a similar question [Is it possible to use django's custom template tags to insert code in other blocks in the template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13624487/is-it-possible-to-use-djangos-custom-template-tags-to-insert-code-in-other-bloc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you find block tag?

base.html

```
<head>
  {% block extra_css %}{% endblock %}
<head>
```

view.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
 {% block extra_css %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="YOUR URL">
 {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Hi,thanks for getting back - yes, I know you can extend templates in views (sorry, should have mentioned that). I want to do something similar in inclusion template tags (have tried and failed) in particular. Say you have a tag to display images using slick-carousel, having the ability to include the JS within the html would be useful, so I don't have to manually add it to base.html. Also here's the link to info about the yii2 asset manager http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html

Comment: by default in django no such functionality.

Comment: Many thanks for getting back - do you know of any packages which might help? Most of the ones I've looked at relate to the compression of JS and CSS files....